# Traversing elements of Stackpanel

Tags: xaml, stackpanel

I am new to C#/XAML development and I  have just started creating very basic windows phone 8 application. I want to get all the elements (Controls) added in the stackpanel as child to the stackpanel using stackpanel.Children.Add(name_of_the_control).
Now I want to get all the elements or controls added in the stackpanel but do not know how to do it. I have searched on the net but could not get helpful link.

Please help me with the process of how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access all controls added to StackPanel from it's `Children` property, for example :

```
foreach(var control in stackpanel.Children)
{
    //here you can get each element of stackpanel in control variable
    //further example :
    if(control is RadioButton)
    {
        var radio = (RadioButton)control;
        //do something with RadioButton
    }
    else if(control is TextBlock)
    {
        var textblok = (TextBlock)control;
        //do something with TextBlock
    }
    //add other possible type of control you want to manipulate
}
```